# How to match regex untill 2 linebreaks

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to strip metadata from some news articles I got from Lexis Nexis. I'm currently having some trouble with stripping multiline meta data, that is: my pattern only matches the first line.

I suspect this could be fixed with a negative lookahead that looks for multiple line breaks, but so far I've not been able to work it out.

```
$article = "SECTION: Media; Blz. 33

LENGTH: 355 woorden

HIGHLIGHT: Verkiezingen Robert Jensen keert vanaf vandaag terug op de
Nederlandse televisie. In 'Jensen kiest voor Amerika' onderzoekt hij de
aantrekkingskracht van Donald Trump. Is hij definitief terug of lonkt misschien
een oude liefde?

Waarom ben je Jensen kiest voor Amerika gaan maken?

,,Ik vind Amerika al mijn hele leven een fascinerend land, ben er vaak en volg
de verkiezingen als fenomeen. Toen Trump maar bleef winnen, begon het idee voor
een tv-programma te leven. Ik wilde alles van die Trump-aanhangers weten want
daar hoor je weinig over.''";

preg_match_all( "/[A-Z\h-]+: *[^\r]+/", $article, $matches);

var_dump( $matches[0] );
die();
```

**Results in:**

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(23) "SECTION: Media; Blz. 33" [1]=> string(19) "LENGTH: 355 woorden" [2]=> string(70) "HIGHLIGHT: Verkiezingen Robert Jensen keert vanaf vandaag terug op de" }
```

As you can only the first line of the *highlight* data is matched.

I've also put a full article (with multiple examples of multiline metadata) up on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PZ9Cti/1).

### Edit:

After two answers I realise that my question may not have been totally clear -- sorry about that.

I'm trying to strip/remove the meta data from `$article` so that only the body of the article is left. In my example I'm using `preg_match_all()`. Once I can correctly match the meta tags, I'll use `preg_replace()` to replace it with an empty string. I considered using preg_split(), but than I'd have to guess which of the array items is the actual body -- a meta tag could be longer then the actual body, although that's not a likely scenario.

So what is **meta tag**? A meta tag always starts with `[A-Z\h-]+:` and ends with a blank line, i.e. two line breaks.

If you take the aforementioned example and put the tags in an array and the article body in a separate variable it'd look like this:

```
<?php
$meta_tags = [
"SECTION"   => "Media; Blz. 33",
"LENGTH"    => "355 woorden",
"HIGHLIGHT" => "Verkiezingen Robert Jensen keert vanaf vandaag terug op de
Nederlandse televisie. In 'Jensen kiest voor Amerika' onderzoekt hij de
aantrekkingskracht van Donald Trump. Is hij definitief terug of lonkt misschien
een oude liefde?"
];

$article_body = "Waarom ben je Jensen kiest voor Amerika gaan maken?

,,Ik vind Amerika al mijn hele leven een fascinerend land, ben er vaak en volg
de verkiezingen als fenomeen. Toen Trump maar bleef winnen, begon het idee voor
een tv-programma te leven. Ik wilde alles van die Trump-aanhangers weten want
daar hoor je weinig over.''";
```

*Additional note*: There may also be some more meta tags after the body's article, but the `preg_replace()` on meta tags should also take care of that.

Comment: Have you tried using `str_replace` to strip the double newlines out first?

Comment: What is that you need to match? Please explain the rules and example output.

Comment: You need to show your expected output.

Comment: Actually you don't want to match until two line-breaks, because your value has several instances of two line-breaks. :) You need instead a positive look-ahead that registers the next meta-key or the end of your data as a single segment. See the answer(s) below.

Comment: Won't need a separate `preg_match_all` if all you want is to remove the metadata, straight on `preg_replace` what you'd match. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. I already mentioned that I in my question though: "In my example I'm using preg_match_all(). Once I can correctly match the meta tags, I'll use preg_replace() to replace it with an empty string."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have no complex matching to do, you could also go with a simple `preg_split()` that targets the metadata keys as delimiters, and not worry about look-aheads etc.:

```
$matches = preg_split( '/\v*([A-Z\h-]+):\h?/', $article, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Gives you:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=> string(7) "SECTION"
  [1]=> string(14) "Media; Blz. 33"
  [2]=> string(6) "LENGTH"
  [3]=> string(11) "355 woorden"
  [4]=> string(9) "HIGHLIGHT"
  [5]=> string(556) "Verkiezingen Robert Jensen keert vanaf vandaag terug op de
Nederlandse televisie. In 'Jensen kiest voor Amerika' onderzoekt hij de
aantrekkingskracht van Donald Trump. Is hij definitief terug of lonkt misschien
een oude liefde?

Waarom ben je Jensen kiest voor Amerika gaan maken?
/...snip/"
}
```

... which I'm sure you can process onward easily enough, evens are keys and odds are values. ^_^

---

**But if you do want to use a look-ahead**, here's an example:

```
preg_match_all('/[A-Z\h-]+:.*?(?=\s*(?:[A-Z\h-]+:|\Z))/s', $article, $matches);
```

This matches anything that starts with your meta-key, followed by anything that's followed by another meta-key or the end of your data. Better not worry about matching line-breaks here, match what matters instead. The look-ahead could be simplified further to simply `(?=[A-Z\h-]+:|\Z)`, but the `\s*` trims the trailing space in the values. (And that's why the subsequent actual look-ahead group is specified as `?:` non-capture, we don't want to clutter the output now do we.) Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(23) "SECTION: Media; Blz. 33"
  [1]=> string(19) "LENGTH: 355 woorden"
  [2]=> string(567) "HIGHLIGHT: Verkiezingen Robert Jensen keert vanaf vandaag terug op de
Nederlandse televisie. In 'Jensen kiest voor Amerika' onderzoekt hij de
aantrekkingskracht van Donald Trump. Is hij definitief terug of lonkt misschien
een oude liefde?

Waarom ben je Jensen kiest voor Amerika gaan maken?
/...snip/"
}
```

---

**But if you want to make it nice**, rather do this:

```
preg_match_all('/([A-Z\h-]+):\h*(.*?)(?=\s*(?:[A-Z\h-]+:|\Z))/s', $article, $matches);
$parsed = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

That is, we're adding capture-groups for the key and the value, and then combining them into an associative array. (Do check if you have matches before trying to combine.) Result:

```
array(3) {
  ["SECTION"]=> string(14) "Media; Blz. 33"
  ["LENGTH"]=> string(11) "355 woorden"
  ["HIGHLIGHT"]=> string(556) "Verkiezingen Robert Jensen keert vanaf vandaag terug op de
Nederlandse televisie. In 'Jensen kiest voor Amerika' onderzoekt hij de
aantrekkingskracht van Donald Trump. Is hij definitief terug of lonkt misschien
een oude liefde?

Waarom ben je Jensen kiest voor Amerika gaan maken?
/...snip/"
}
```

---

**Edit** If all you really want is the body text (now that it's clear where the body text begins: after a one-para highlight meta), and you have no use for the metadata, then just clean up the article with `preg_replace` matching all sections that start with the meta-key, and match everything 'til the first double (or more) linebreak. (Use `\v` to match any vertical space.)

```
$article = preg_replace('/([A-Z\h-]+):\h*(.*?)[\v]{2,}/s', '', $article);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. You're answer matched the article body with the highlight-tag, probably because I didn't explain the difference properly. I've edited my question, hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: The last regex + array_combine above will itemize everything in the data you feed into it. So you're saying that the body text begins after the HIGHLIGHT tag that's followed by a one-paragraph snippet, and then begin actual content? In that case, you can use what's matched under the highlight-key, and simply remove the first paragraph.

Comment: Otherwise, if all you really want is the body text, and all meta goes to the bin, then just use `preg_replace` that starts with the key and matches everything 'til the first double (or more) linebreak. `/([A-Z\h-]+):\h*(.*?)[\v]{2,}/s` wil do it. Your original regex BTW only matches `\r`, so you may run into problems with `\n`s -- better use `\v` for matching any vertical space.

Comment: Thanks! `/([A-Z\h-]+):\h*(.*?)[\v]{2,}/s` does exactly what I want it to do. In fact I had already tried `/([A-Z\h-]+):\h*(.*?)[\v]{2,}/`, but that didn't match my multiline tags (not even the first line). Of course switching to DOTALL mode would've helped a whole lot.

Comment: Haha yes dotall mode helps for sure, especially whatwith all those ragged margins you've got there. There's your next regexing then, cleaning them up. Should be easy!

Comment: Yeah... It's a total mess. Should be easy though, `trim()` actually does a decent job. .txt and .doc are the only ways to get the full article text. The batch downloads they offer for .csv and .html (which would be a lot easier to read) only supply the meta tags and an extract of the article (for html). I guess they do that to keep analysing this stuff fun...

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
^(?P<key>[A-Z]+):
(?P<value>(?:(?!^[A-Z]+:).)+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/9HIslu/1).

Comment: Thanks! That doesn't do what I was looking for, though. But I probably didn't formulate my question as I should've. I've edited.